# How to reduce huge arguments list in Composable function in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, clean-architecture

I'm building quite complex app, and at some point I've noticed that my composable function is getting really huge, and I suspect it is not a good practice. Is there a pattern/solution I can implement and follow in the future to avoid these huge composables?

```
TopSection(
                filterParametersState = filterParametersState,
                itineraryCount = viewModel.flightData.value.result?.itineraryCount ?: 0,
                buttonNames = viewModel.buttonNames,
                selectedButtonIndex = viewModel.selectedButtonIndex.value,
                selectedButtonName = viewModel.selectedButtonName.value,
                isThemeSwitchChecked = themeViewModel.isDarkTheme,
                onDurationButtonClicked = { buttonName -> viewModel.updateFilterMaxDuration(buttonName) },
                onThemeSwitchClicked = { themeViewModel.switchTheme() },
                onSliderValueChange = { valueFromSlider -> viewModel.updateFilterMaxPrice(valueFromSlider) },
                onParamsUpperClicked = { buttonIndex, buttonName ->
                    viewModel.updateSelectedButtonIndex(buttonIndex)
                    viewModel.updateIsDialogOpen()
                    viewModel.updateSelectedButtonName(buttonName)
                },
                onParamsBottomClicked = { buttonName ->
                    if (buttonName != "SAVE") {
                        viewModel.updateIsDialogOpen()
                        viewModel.updateSelectedButtonName(buttonName)
                    } else {
                        commonViewModel.updateCurrentFlightParams(viewModel.flightSearch.value)
                        viewModel.getFlights()
                    }
                }
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following methods can be used to cut down on the amount of arguments in your composable function:

Group similar parameters into a data class: You can group related arguments into a data class rather than sending them individually. By doing this, the function call may become shorter and simpler to read.

Use default parameter values: You can give default parameter values for parameters that are optional. This could simplify the function call and require fewer arguments.

Comment: Could you provide an example how grouping similar parameters into a data class would look like?

Comment: please check that i mentioned in next answer

Answer (score 0):

```
data class abc(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val address: String
)

@Composable
fun RandomFunction(obj: abc) {
    // ...
}
```

//edited

```
    onDurationButtonClicked = { buttonName -> 
       //make here function 
       buttonFunction(buttonName) //this is function calling
    } 
//make here function impl

   fun buttonFunction(parameter){ 
      viewModel.updateFilterMaxDuration(buttonName) 
   }
```

Comment: Okay, I get it with value arguments, however as you can see in my case the most arguments are functions. How can I solve that?

Comment: i get it, 
onDurationButtonClicked{ buttonName ->
//make here function buttonFunction(buttonName)
}


//make here function impl
buttonFunction(parameter){
   viewModel.updateFilterMaxDuration(buttonName) 
}
like  that

Comment: please check that i just edited in above

Comment: Sorry, but I don't fully understand your answer. It seems to me like I did everything just like you described. If you use this solution, you then have to pass the function somewhere, in my case it's TopSection, and it gets messy

Comment: can you look edited section again